# Saving data to database and exporting to excel

Tags: database, forms, export

I'm creating a form in a blog for users to register their emails so I can send a newsletter later but I don't want to use any newsletter plugin for that.

I'd like to save the emails and than export them to something else like excel or a cvs file.

Is there any plugin or any other solution to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options:

- the [cformsII](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/) plugin, with tracking enabled
- the [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/), plus the Contact Form 7 to Database Extension

other may be suitable as well!

Comment: By the way, I used the Contact Form 7 plugin. Great tip!